# PWA OAuth login

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a progressive web app that lets the user have the option to login through the app with either facebook or google. I'm using Node.js with Passport.js to authenticate the user. The problem here is that on iOS safari opens when passport redirects to the users login choice and stays in safari when logged in and its basically the same on Android but with chrome.
Is there any simple solution to this or is it just not possible to do at the moment with PWA's?

Comment: Fixed on Android with Chrome Canary version 68.0.3400.0

Thread: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=771418#c84

Still a problem on iOS tho.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix this by **removing** the manifest meta tag:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/tracker/site.webmanifest">
```

Hope it works for you too, wasted 2 days trying to find a solution.